# How to handle non availability of row during sql execution

Tags: python, mysql-python

How are you supposed to handle exceptions when there are no rows for this id. How should the calling code handle this

```
  def function(id)
    mysql_conn = MySQLdb.connect(..)    
    cursor = mysql_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""select val from fooo where id = %s""", (id))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    return row[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I find myself fetching just one row I always like to use the following (although not the best performance wise) construct.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM foo;")
for row in cursor:
    return row
# No row handling behind the loop.
return "No rows found"
```

This effectively returns when the first iteration of the loop runs. Which can only happen if there is at least `1` row in the result set. And otherwise will run the code **behind** the `for` loop.

You can raise a custom exception, or return a special value such as `None` that lets the calling function know nicely that there were no rows.

Comment: I actually need to return an integer value, so I wouldn't want to string values.

Comment: @Joe, of course you can return anything you want there instead of the string. It was an example `return 0` or `return -1` would also work.